# How to join two SqlExpression With And Condition using Servicestack.Ormlite

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I need to filter out some data at generic class, I don't know how to join two `SqlExpression<T>` with `AND` condition. I tryed:

```
public List<T> Select(SqlExpression<T> expression)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    using (var db = OpenConnection().Open())
    {
        if (_stores)
        {
            list = db.Select<T>(expression);
        }
        else
        {
            var q = db.From<T>().Where(x => (x as EntityBase).store_id == _store_id);
            list = db.Select<T>(q, expression);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

But this is not working

```
list = db.Select<T>(q, expression); // this is not working
```

Comment: Please don't address your questions to specific users, this is an open Q/A site where anyone who knows the answer should be able to help you which addressing your questions to individuals discourages.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlExpression<T>` [OrmLite's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) typed query builder, there can only be 1 query builder so you can't merge 2 query builders together, you need to apply whatever conditions you want to the existing query builder, e.g:

```
public List<T> Select(SqlExpression<T> expression) =>
    db.Select(expression.And(x => (x as EntityBase).store_id == _store_id));
```